# Make a div floated but keep it centered when the space is not enough

Tags: jquery, css, layout, html

I want to have something like a grid where when there is no enough space on the window for more than 1 element each element stays centenred, but when there is more space they get floated to the left. Is there a way to achieve this using only css?

Comment: Can you rephrase the question. Hard to understand.

Comment: This is default div behaviour isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

This would involve changing the margin-left and margin-right properties of an element when the window is resized, which is not possible without JavaScript.

Without JavaScript, your code will look something like this:

```
<html><body style="margin:0px">
<div style="min-height: 400px; min-width: 600px; clear: both;">
<div style="margin: 10px; float: left; margin-right: 95px; margin-left: 95px;width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: Red;"></div>
<div style="margin: 10px; float: left; margin-right: 95px; margin-left: 95px;width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: Blue;"></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You could center the div for a minimum width case, but you need JavaScript to manipulate the margin sizes when the window is resized.